# how can i click imageview inside a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have this "activity_cart.xml":

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listOrder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtDetail"/>
```

with this "ActivityCart.java"

```
public class ActivityCart extends AppCompatActivity {

// declare view objects
ListView listOrder;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtTotalLabel, txtTotal, txtAlert;
RelativeLayout lytOrder;
ImageView removeProd;

// declate dbhelper and adapter objects
DBHelper dbhelper;
AdapterCart mola;


// declare static variables to store tax and currency data
public static double Tax;
public static String Currency;

// declare arraylist variable to store data
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data;
public static ArrayList<Integer> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<String> Menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> Quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static ArrayList<Double> Sub_total_price = new ArrayList<Double>();

double Total_price;
final int CLEAR_ALL_ORDER = 0;
final int CLEAR_ONE_ORDER = 1;
int FLAG;
int ID;
String TaxCurrencyAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;

// create price format
DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_cart);
    }

    FloatingActionButton clear = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabClear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showClearDialog(CLEAR_ALL_ORDER, 1111);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton checkout = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabCheckout);
    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dbhelper.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityCart.this, ActivityCheckout.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // connect view objects with xml id
    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    listOrder = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);
    txtTotalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotalLabel);
    txtTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    removeProd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.removeProd);

    lytOrder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytOrder);

    // tax and currency API url
    TaxCurrencyAPI = Config.ADMIN_PANEL_URL + "/api/get-tax-and-currency.php" + "?accesskey=" + Config.AccessKey;

    mola = new AdapterCart(this);
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

    // open database
    try {
        dbhelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    // call asynctask class to request tax and currency data from server
    new getTaxCurrency().execute();

   // event listener to handle list when clicked
    listOrder.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
                // show confirmation dialog
                showClearDialog(CLEAR_ONE_ORDER, Menu_ID.get(position));
            }
     });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cart, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            this.finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.checkout:
            dbhelper.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityCart.this, ActivityCheckout.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            showClearDialog(CLEAR_ALL_ORDER, 1111);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// method to create dialog
void showClearDialog(int flag, int id) {
    FLAG = flag;
    ID = id;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm);
    switch (FLAG) {
        case 0:
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.clear_all_order));
            break;
        case 1:
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.clear_one_order));
            break;
    }
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (FLAG) {
                case 0:
                    // clear all menu in order table
                    dbhelper.deleteAllData();
                    listOrder.invalidateViews();
                    clearData();
                    new getDataTask().execute();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // clear selected menu in order table
                    dbhelper.deleteData(ID);
                    listOrder.invalidateViews();
                    clearData();
                    new getDataTask().execute();
                    break;
            }

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // close dialog
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // show progressbar first
    getTaxCurrency() {
        if (!prgLoading.isShown()) {
            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // parse json data from server in background
        parseJSONDataTax();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // if internet connection available request data form server
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if (IOConnect == 0) {
            new getDataTask().execute();
        } else {
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtAlert.setText(R.string.alert);
        }

    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONDataTax() {

    try {
        // request data from tax and currency API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

        JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1);
        JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Currency = currency.getString("Value");


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// clear arraylist variables before used
void clearData() {
    Menu_ID.clear();
    Menu_name.clear();
    Quantity.clear();
    Sub_total_price.clear();
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask() {
        if (!prgLoading.isShown()) {
            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lytOrder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // get data from database
        getDataFromDatabase();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // show data
        txtTotal.setText(Total_price + " " + Currency);
        txtTotalLabel.setText(getString(R.string.total_order) + " (Tax " + Tax + "%)");
        prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // if data available show data on list
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if (Menu_ID.size() > 0) {
            lytOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listOrder.setAdapter(mola);
        } else {
            txtAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}

// method to get data from server
public void getDataFromDatabase() {

    Total_price = 0;
    clearData();
    data = dbhelper.getAllData();

    // store data to arraylist variables
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(i);

        Menu_ID.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString()));
        Menu_name.add(row.get(1).toString());
        Quantity.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(2).toString()));
        Sub_total_price.add(Double.parseDouble(formatData.format(Double.parseDouble(row.get(3).toString()))));
        Total_price += Sub_total_price.get(i);
    }

    // count total order
    Total_price -= (Total_price * (Tax / 100));
    Total_price = Double.parseDouble(formatData.format(Total_price));
}

// when back button pressed close database and back to previous page
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    dbhelper.close();
    finish();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

and this "AdapterCart.java"

```
public class AdapterCart extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AdapterCart(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ActivityCart.Menu_ID.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lsv_item_order_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtMenuName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMenuName);
            holder.txtQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            holder.removeProd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeProd);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.txtMenuName.setText(ActivityCart.Menu_name.get(position));
        holder.txtQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(ActivityCart.Quantity.get(position)));
        holder.txtPrice.setText(ActivityCart.Sub_total_price.get(position)+" "+ActivityCart.Currency);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtMenuName, txtQuantity, txtPrice;
        ImageView removeProd;
    }


}
```

and finally "layout lsv_item_order_list.xml":

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMenuName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFlacon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="150dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtMenuName"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="100 Tab."
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qtyMinus"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtQuantity"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_minus" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtFlacon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qtyPlus"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtQuantity"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMenuName"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/removeProd"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Currently when i push on listOrder my cart item deletes.
My question is how to delete cart item when i press the ImageView with id "removeProd" inside layout lsv_item_order_list.xml.

I hove somebody could help me.

Comment: holder.removeprod.setonclicklistener this try bro

Comment: The "holder.removeProd.setOnClickListener()" not working. I tried already.

Comment: why not working its the way to add click on listview list items. holder.image.setonClickListener(new View.onclocklsitner) and its override method onclick

Comment: you can provide full code please?

Comment: holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                holder.itemClicked(folder.getPath());
            }
        });

Comment: Still not working. So i want to do the click from ActivityCart not from AdapterCart and find the position of "Menu_ID.get(position)" in order to delete the desired product. Here is my all cod of ActivityCart:

Comment: i edited my question with the all code in ActivityCart above

Comment: add listner in your adapter cart adapter

Comment: i do not know how to do that :)

Comment: holder.removeProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
     holder.removeProd.performClick();(to what??)
    }
   });

Comment: in your adapter getview function add this listner

Comment: what listner to add?

Comment: holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) {  } });

Comment: I understend that but beetwen brakets what to put to access this from ActivityCart: listOrder.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
                // show confirmation dialog
                showClearDialog(CLEAR_ONE_ORDER, Menu_ID.get(position));
            }
     });

Comment: when click on this call the call back from adapter and on callback receive write this function showClearDialog(CLEAR_ONE_ORDER, Menu_ID.get(position)); } })

Comment: Provide me the full code please. And sorry for the amount of questions :)

Comment: i am unable to answer here in your question

Comment: send to this email: nistoralin87@hotmail.com

Comment: I resolve it. Thanx for all answers :)

Comment: really good happy to see this